# Call to a member function reflash() on string

Tags: php, laravel

I have a *verify function* in my *PaymentController* :

```
public function verify(Request $request)
{
    $request->session()->flash('address', $request['address']);
    $request->session()->flash('send', $request['send']);
    return redirect(route('cart.payment.pay'));
}
```

As you can see this function returned to `cart.payment.pay` with 2 sessions `address` and `send`

In `cart.payment.pay` i have a new function for show blade :

```
public function pay()
{
    session('send')->reflash();
    return view('home.payment.pay');
}
```

In this function i have a new blade with new form, i want to reflash and keep my session until this page `home.payment.pay`.

but i have this error :

```
Error
Call to a member function reflash() on string
```

How can i reflash and keep my session ?

Comment: And what does the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/session#flash-data) say?

Comment: i even use session()->keep(), but its not working and return for me null, i dont know where i have to use keep or reflash

Comment: Your issue is you are using session('send'), this retireves the value of send in the session. Please see https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/session#flash-data.

Comment: Ok, but i dont have $request in my pay function, i have to use $request in this function ?

Comment: oh i undrestood this, thanks

Comment: @sta i'm ready if you have time :)